# Shared Angular component in nativescript app, not showing up

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a BottomNavigation component, which needs to show up in 3 other components: OrderComponent, UserAreaComponent and Locations Component.

I implement the  component like this:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="My Yooji's"></Label>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout class="page p-t-15" rows="*,60">
    <ScrollView row="0">
        <Label text="MyYooji's Area"></Label>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal">
        <bottom-navigation></bottom-navigation>            <---- HERE
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

The BottomNavigation component is imported in the app.module.ts @NgModule under declarations:

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ApiService,
        UserService,
        AuthGuard,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        BottomNavigationComponent       <---- DECLARED
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
```

Like this the  is not rendered.

**What is the right way to make the BottomNavigation component available globally in other components?**

Addition:
If I import the BottomNavigationComponent in the declarations array of for example the order.module.ts of the Order Component, the bottom-navigation shows up within the Order Component. But like this, the bottom-navigation is not available in other components than the order component...

bottom-navigation.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "bottom-navigation",
  templateUrl: "./bottom-navigation.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./bottom-navigation.component.scss"]
})
export class BottomNavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  navItems = [
    {id: 1, name: "My Yooji's", targetUrl: "myyoojis", img: "myyoojis24.png"},
    {id: 2, name: "Order", targetUrl: "order", img: "order24.png"},
    {id: 3, name: "Locations", targetUrl: "locations", img: "locations24.png"}
  ];
  activeNavItemId: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.activeNavItem);
   }

  onNavItemTap(navItem) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(navItem.targetUrl);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply putting the BottomNavigationModule into @NgModules imports instead of declarations has done the trick.

```
imports: [
    // other imports removed
    BottomNavigationModule
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Lazy Loading Modules then you have to import 'BottomNavigation ' in every module you want to use it.